# Documentation framework for WEB API's

Tags: api, rest, asp.net-web-api

I am using [Swagger](http://swagger.io/) to document my API, but I am looking for an alternative tool that **allows my API to have multiple "methods" with the same VERB+PATH, example:**

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Customer")]
public class CustomerController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    public ClienteDTO GetCustomerByContractId(int contractId)
    {
        //...
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    public ClienteDTO GetCustomerByAccountId(int accountId)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

This works fine in ASP.NET WEB API given that a "GET" request will hit the right method on the server side:

```
http://example.com/api/Customer?contractId=1
http://example.com/api/Customer?accountId=1
```

But Swagger do not support this (https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec/issues/182).

Someone knows an alternative documentation framework that supports this?

Comment: That is not the proper way to design an API. The paths for these two API should be something like this: `api/customer/contract/{id}` and `api/customer/account/{id}`

Comment: Ops... just noticed this is a very old question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a NuGet package from Microsoft that doesn't have this limitation:

```
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage
```

[image]

It's oficial from Microsoft and its very easy to customize because it adds files to your solution (a controller, a css and some cshtml files). The only problem is that you cannot make test calls to your API like in swashbuckle (I say, do a POST, GET, etc directly from your documentation page). I did some modifications in the cshtml files and added this functionality very easily.